# MirageJS - How Do You Add "blob://http://localhost" To Whitelist / Passthrough?

Tags: ember-cli-mirage, miragejs

I have functionality that takes a local base64 URL for an image and converts it to actual base64 data.  To do this, I have to call `fetch()`, followed by an initialization of `new FileReader()`.

When the browser tries to fetch the local base64 URL (ie. `blob:http://localhost:3000/41c20923-c818-4e22-a4`), Mirage tells me that there was no route configured to handle this request.

I've tried adding the following to my exported `mockServer()` function:

`this.passthrough('blob://http://localhost:3000')`
`this.passthrough('blob://http://localhost:3000/**')`
`this.passthrough()` (this whitelists all calls to `http://localhost:3000`)

but none of the above actually whitelists calls to `blob:http://localhost`.  What's the right way to mock out a fetch here?

Comment: I have the same question, did you find a solution?